# flutter onesignal add problems "Expected to find project root in current working directory."

Tags: flutter, onesignal

When I want to add onesignal to flutter, I get the following error. How can I solve it?

[PROBLEM PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O62To.png)

Comment: Are you running this command in your project folder?

Comment: no, dont project work

Comment: I mean are you running this command in your application folder?

Comment: i run this command where flutter is installed

Comment: But you have to run this command in your application folder.

Answer (score 10):

You'll get this error if you try run a command from outside the root of your flutter project folder. Simply type `pwd` in your project terminal, and the command will output the full path of your working directory. In VSCode, you can quickly access the project root folder terminal by right clicking the folder then "open in integrated terminal".

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing this situation and i noticed i deleted my pubspec.yaml

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33055127)

Comment: Lol. thank you. I just did the same.

Answer (score 3):

You will get this error if you type 'flutter pub get <>' instead of 'flutter pub add <>' in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I have also experience this error before. But in my case it happends that I opened the folder the folder the main project is wrapped around. So I had to navigate one step to open the main folder that contains the project source files in android studio and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a project in one file and run it from an external file, the same problem arises. To solve this problem, name the project, that is, show the file and then run

ThisOneIMG   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpAo6.png)
ThisTwoIMG   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUEU9.png)

The first picture shows the problem and the second one shows how the problem was solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).